# Scaling Transformations - Scalar Field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, action

I've started self-studying QFT and I am using some Cambridge notes (Tong's). There is a specific excersise where we are asked to see how the action

$$S=\int d^4x\left(\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi-\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2-g\phi^p\right)$$ transforms when

$$x\rightarrow x'=\lambda x\quad\text{and}\quad\phi(x) \rightarrow \phi'(x)= \lambda^{-D}\phi(\lambda^{-1}x)$$

where we can define for simplicity $y=\lambda^{-1}x=\lambda^{-2}x'$. In the notes he is saying that:

$$\frac{\partial \phi(x)}{\partial x^\nu}\rightarrow \frac{\partial x'^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\nu}}\frac{\partial \phi'(x)}{\partial x'^{\mu}}=λ\frac{\partial }{\partial x'^{\mu}}(λ^{-D}\phi(λ^{-1}x))=λ^{-(1+D)}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{\mu}}\phi(y)\tag{A1}$$

and that

$$\int d^4x=λ^4\int d^4y\tag{B1}$$

**Those two do not make sense to me!!!** since I would work it out as follows:

$$\frac{\partial \phi(x)}{\partial x^\nu}\rightarrow (\frac{\partial \phi(x)}{\partial x^\nu})'=\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x'^{\nu}}\frac{\partial \phi'(x)}{\partial x^{\mu}}=λ^{-1}\frac{\partial }{\partial x^{\mu}}(λ^{-D}\phi(λ^{-1}x))=λ^{-(2+D)}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{\mu}}\phi(y)\tag{A2}$$

and

$$\int d^4x \rightarrow \left(\int d^4x\right)'=\lambda^8\int d^4y\tag{B2}$$

Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong? Why are the correct transformation relations not (A2) and (B2) instead of (A1) and (B1)?

Comment: It looks like your main problem is your derivative did not transform correctly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_transformation

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't see the mistake. The derivative of  a scalar field transforms as a vector as $\frac{\partial \phi(x)}{\partial x^\nu}\rightarrow (\frac{\partial \phi(x)}{\partial x^\nu})'=\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x'^{\nu}}\frac{\partial \phi'(x)}{\partial x^{\mu}}$. Or is there a misconception on my behalf?

Comment: Helen can you link the notes and the pages you're referring to?

Comment: [link](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/r.ribeiro/supervisions.html).  It is the 9th problem in the QFT1 sheet.

Answer (score 4):

Your confusion is because in transforming the action $S' \rightarrow S$ you do an "extra" transformation of the variable $x$ when in reality $x$ is just a "dummy" variable that is integrated over. Equations should help make this clear.

Let's make this completely general. We are interested in the effect on the action functional from a transformation affecting both the positions and the fields:

\begin{equation}
x \rightarrow x' \\
\Phi(x) \rightarrow \Phi'(x') = \mathcal{F}(\Phi(x)).
\end{equation}
Written in this way, $\Phi$ is affected by the transformation in two ways. The first is a functional change in the field $\Phi' = \mathcal{F}(\Phi)$ and the second a change in the argument $x \rightarrow x'$.

For a generic Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$,
\begin{align}
S' &= \int d^dx~\mathcal{L}(\Phi'(x), \partial_{\mu} \Phi'(x)) \\
&= \int d^dx'~\mathcal{L}(\Phi'(x'), \partial_{\mu}' \Phi'(x')) \\
&= \int d^dx'~\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{F}(\Phi(x)), \partial_{\mu}' \mathcal{F}(\Phi(x))) \\
&= \int d^dx~ \Big|\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}\Big|~\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{F}(\Phi(x)), (\partial x^{\nu}/ \partial x'^{\mu})\partial_{\nu} \mathcal{F}(\Phi(x))).
\end{align}
In the second line there is a change of the integration variable $x \rightarrow x'$; in the third line we express $\Phi'(x')$ in terms $\Phi(x)$; in the last line we express $x'$ in terms of $x$.

$\textbf{Note:}$ At the very beginning, in going from $S \rightarrow S'$, the reason we substitute $\Phi'(x)$ for $\Phi(x)$ (and $\textit{not}$ $\Phi'(x')$), is that since the action integrates over $x$ it is just an integration or "dummy" variable that can be renamed. To see the $\textit{functional}$ change in the action we have to look at how it changes under a new function, in this case $\Phi(x) \rightarrow \Phi'(x)$.

This is why for the specific case
\begin{equation}
x\rightarrow x'=\lambda x\quad\text{and}\quad\phi(x) \rightarrow \phi'(x)= \lambda^{-D}\phi(\lambda^{-1}x)
\end{equation}
with $y=\lambda^{-1}x=\lambda^{-2}x'$, that
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \phi(x)}{\partial x^\nu}\rightarrow \frac{\partial x'^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\nu}}\frac{\partial \phi'(x)}{\partial x'^{\mu}}=λ\frac{\partial }{\partial x'^{\mu}}(λ^{-D}\phi(λ^{-1}x))=λ^{-(1+D)}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{\mu}}\phi(y)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\int d^4x=λ^4\int d^4y.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

In the same spirit and notation as eigenschwarz's solution, but perhaps a bit more directly, one can say it as follows: under $x\to x' = \lambda x$, the field $\phi$ transforms to

$$\phi(x)\to \phi'(x') \equiv F[\phi(x)] = \lambda^{-D} \phi(\lambda^{-1} x) $$

Remark: one derives this transformation from exponentiating the representation of infinitesimal dilatations acting on fields. This is described nicely in Di Francesco et al, *Conformal Field Theory*, chapter 4.2.1.

To avoid possible confusion, let's write this with a general argument:
$$\phi'(y) = \lambda^{-D}\phi(\lambda^{-1}y)$$

The action $S[\phi]$ transforms to $S'[\phi']$, where $S'[\phi']$ is simply the integral over the same Lagrangian with $\phi\to \phi'$ (as eigenschwarz writes). Note that we're deliberately *not* writing $\phi(x)$ or $\phi'(x')$ because the spacetime position is a dummy variable that's integrated over (as eigenschwarz explains clearly).

For simplicity, let's look only at the kinetic term.

\begin{align}
S'[\phi']
&= \frac{1}{2} \int d^dx\; 
\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} \phi'(x)\right]^2
\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int d^dx\; 
\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} \lambda^{-D} \phi(\lambda^{-1}x)\right]^2
\end{align}
Now we do a change of integration variable so that the argument of the field matches the integration variable: $y^\mu\equiv \lambda^{-1}x^\mu$
\begin{align}
S'[\phi'] 
&= \frac{1}{2} \lambda^{-2D} \int d^dy\, \lambda^d 
\;  \left[
\lambda^{-1}
\frac{\partial}{\partial y^\nu} \phi(y)\right]^2
\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \lambda^{d-2D-2} \int d^dy
\;  \left[
\frac{\partial}{\partial y^\nu} \phi(y)\right]^2
\end{align}

Here we see that $S'[\phi'] = \lambda^{d-2D-2} S[\phi]$; this is clear from recognizing that $y$ is simply a dummy variable. Thus when $d=4$, the kinetic term of the action is dilatation-invariant when $D = 1$. The other terms in the action are straightforward to analyze in the same way.